Polars NDCG optimized calculation
The problem here is to implement NDCG calculation on Polars that would be efficient for huge datasets.
Main idea of NDCG is to calculate DCG and IDCG, let's skip the gain part and only think about discount part, which depends on ranks from ideal and proposed orderings.
So the tricky part for me here is to properly and effectively calculate the positions of similar items from ideal and proposed parts, i.e.:
ideal:   a b c d e f
propsed: d b g e h

so we have intersection of {b, d, e} items with idx_ideal=[2,4,5] (starting from 1) and idx_propsed=[2,1,4]
So what I want is to calculate those idx_proposed and idx_ideal for dataframe with columns (user, ideal, proposed),
so the resulting DF would have columns: (user, ideal, proposed, idx_ideal, idx_propsed)
# so its only ideal idx, then I create extra for proposed idx and join them
(
    df
        .explode('ideal')
        .with_columns(idx=pl.int_range(pl.len()).over('user'))
        .filter(pl.col('ideal').is_in(pl.col('proposed')))
        .group_by('user', maintain_order=True)
        .agg(pl.col('idx'))
)

I explode ideal over user and find position by adding extra idx column and leaving only ideal=proposed rows, but this results in extra DF with a subset of rows, which I would have to join back, which is probably not very optimal. Then I have to calculate it once again for proposed side.
Moreover, I will have to explode over (idx_ideal, idx_proposed) on the next step to calculate user's IDCG, DCG and NDCG.
Could you help me optimize those calculations?
I think I should use that users do not interact with each-other and separate rows could be processed separately.
Here is the random data generator
import polars as pl
import random

num_users = 100_000
min_len = 10
max_len = 200
item_range = 10_000

def generate_user_data():
    length = random.randint(min_len, max_len)
    ideal = random.sample(range(item_range), length)

    length = random.randint(min_len, max_len)
    predicted = random.sample(range(item_range), length)
    
    return ideal, predicted

data = []
for user_id in range(num_users):
    ideal, predicted = generate_user_data()
    data.append({
        'user': user_id,
        'ideal': ideal,
        'proposed': predicted
    })

df = pl.DataFrame(data)
print(df.head())


shape: (5, 3)
┌──────┬──────────────────────┬──────────────────────┐
│ user ┆ ideal                ┆ proposed             │
│ ---  ┆ ---                  ┆ ---                  │
│ i64  ┆ list[i64]            ┆ list[i64]            │
╞══════╪══════════════════════╪══════════════════════╡
│ 0    ┆ [9973, 313, … 5733]  ┆ [8153, 3461, … 4602] │
│ 1    ┆ [3756, 9053, … 1014] ┆ [435, 9407, … 6159]  │
│ 2    ┆ [8152, 1615, … 2873] ┆ [5078, 9006, … 8157] │
│ 3    ┆ [6104, 2929, … 2606] ┆ [5110, 790, … 363]   │
│ 4    ┆ [1863, 6801, … 271]  ┆ [5571, 5555, … 5591] │
└──────┴──────────────────────┴──────────────────────┘



If you can provide actual before and after DataFrames it would be easier for people (who may not know what DCG is) to answer.

@jqurious added random generator for data added to the question

Ah, so it's a list intersection problem. There is: pl.col('ideal').list.set_intersection(pl.col('proposed')) to get the intersection - but I don't think there is a List API method that gives you the indexes.

@jqurious , yeah, exactly, the problem is that I need indexes to calculate discount of ordering mistakes. if I could at least use external columns from list.eval or the index_of PR would be finished :) but for now I guess there is a room for optimization

Wouldn't simple mapping of some function be easier and better? And instead of using lists, maybe it's possible to use numpy arrays for better performance.

In my testing, I got the fastest results by first getting the intersection:

.list.set_intersection()

There is currently no List API method to get the index positions, but it can be emulated if we .flatten() the lists .over() each "row". (we use with_row_index as the group id)

.arg_true() is used to get the indexes where the .is_in() check is True

mapping_strategy="join" will give us back a list column.


pl.Config(fmt_str_lengths=100, fmt_table_cell_list_len=10)

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "user": [1, 2], 
    "ideal": [["a", "b", "c", "d", "a"], ["x", "y", "z"]], 
    "proposed": [["f", "a", "e", "r", "d"], ["y", "e", "s"]]
})

(df
  .with_row_index()
  .with_columns(
     pl.col("ideal").list.set_intersection("proposed")
       .alias("intersection")
  )
  .with_columns(
     pl.col("ideal").flatten().is_in(pl.col("intersection").flatten())
       .arg_true()
       .over("index", mapping_strategy="join")
       .alias("idx_ideal"),
     pl.col("proposed").flatten().is_in(pl.col("intersection").flatten())
       .arg_true()
       .over("index", mapping_strategy="join")
       .alias("idx_proposed")
  )
)

shape: (2, 7)
┌───────┬──────┬───────────────────────────┬───────────────────────────┬──────────────┬───────────┬──────────────┐
│ index ┆ user ┆ ideal                     ┆ proposed                  ┆ intersection ┆ idx_ideal ┆ idx_proposed │
│ ---   ┆ ---  ┆ ---                       ┆ ---                       ┆ ---          ┆ ---       ┆ ---          │
│ u32   ┆ i64  ┆ list[str]                 ┆ list[str]                 ┆ list[str]    ┆ list[u32] ┆ list[u32]    │
╞═══════╪══════╪═══════════════════════════╪═══════════════════════════╪══════════════╪═══════════╪══════════════╡
│ 0     ┆ 1    ┆ ["a", "b", "c", "d", "a"] ┆ ["f", "a", "e", "r", "d"] ┆ ["a", "d"]   ┆ [0, 3, 4] ┆ [1, 4]       │
│ 1     ┆ 2    ┆ ["x", "y", "z"]           ┆ ["y", "e", "s"]           ┆ ["y"]        ┆ [1]       ┆ [0]          │
└───────┴──────┴───────────────────────────┴───────────────────────────┴──────────────┴───────────┴──────────────┘

First appearance only
As per the updated requirements, you could add .is_first_distinct() to pick the first appearance in the case of duplicate values.
(df.with_row_index()
   .with_columns(pl.col("ideal").list.set_intersection("proposed").alias("intersection"))
   .with_columns(
      (
         pl.col("ideal").flatten().is_first_distinct()
         &
         pl.col("ideal").flatten().is_in(pl.col("intersection").flatten())
      )
      .arg_true()
      .over("index", mapping_strategy="join")
      .alias("idx_ideal")
   )
)

shape: (2, 6)
┌───────┬──────┬───────────────────────────┬───────────────────────────┬──────────────┬───────────┐
│ index ┆ user ┆ ideal                     ┆ proposed                  ┆ intersection ┆ idx_ideal │
│ ---   ┆ ---  ┆ ---                       ┆ ---                       ┆ ---          ┆ ---       │
│ u32   ┆ i64  ┆ list[str]                 ┆ list[str]                 ┆ list[str]    ┆ list[u32] │
╞═══════╪══════╪═══════════════════════════╪═══════════════════════════╪══════════════╪═══════════╡
│ 0     ┆ 1    ┆ ["a", "b", "c", "d", "a"] ┆ ["f", "a", "e", "r", "d"] ┆ ["a", "d"]   ┆ [0, 3]    │
│ 1     ┆ 2    ┆ ["x", "y", "z"]           ┆ ["y", "e", "s"]           ┆ ["y"]        ┆ [1]       │
└───────┴──────┴───────────────────────────┴───────────────────────────┴──────────────┴───────────┘

Build expressions with a function
As the expression has become rather complex, it may be desirable to put it inside a helper function.
def index_of_intersection(expr):
    return (
        (
            expr.flatten().is_first_distinct() 
            & 
            expr.flatten().is_in(pl.col("intersection").flatten())
        )
        .arg_true()
        .over("index", mapping_strategy="join")
        .name.prefix("idx_")
    )

And use .pipe() to call it.
(df
  .with_row_index()
  .with_columns(
     pl.col("ideal").list.set_intersection("proposed")
       .alias("intersection")
  )
  .with_columns(
     pl.col("ideal", "proposed").pipe(index_of_intersection)
  )
)

shape: (2, 7)
┌───────┬──────┬───────────────────────────┬───────────────────────────┬──────────────┬───────────┬──────────────┐
│ index ┆ user ┆ ideal                     ┆ proposed                  ┆ intersection ┆ idx_ideal ┆ idx_proposed │
│ ---   ┆ ---  ┆ ---                       ┆ ---                       ┆ ---          ┆ ---       ┆ ---          │
│ u32   ┆ i64  ┆ list[str]                 ┆ list[str]                 ┆ list[str]    ┆ list[u32] ┆ list[u32]    │
╞═══════╪══════╪═══════════════════════════╪═══════════════════════════╪══════════════╪═══════════╪══════════════╡
│ 0     ┆ 1    ┆ ["a", "b", "c", "d", "a"] ┆ ["f", "a", "e", "r", "d"] ┆ ["a", "d"]   ┆ [0, 3]    ┆ [1, 4]       │
│ 1     ┆ 2    ┆ ["x", "y", "z"]           ┆ ["y", "e", "s"]           ┆ ["y"]        ┆ [1]       ┆ [0]          │
└───────┴──────┴───────────────────────────┴───────────────────────────┴──────────────┴───────────┴──────────────┘


I managed to use user as index for rows. There is a thing: there might be different results based on data background, for example, if we have duplicates on different positions we might want to use separate or first-appearance index, the proposed approach works fine for unique items and clear calc (separates), but in recsys we might calc first appearance as a good result

Ah. You could add (pl.col("ideal").flatten().is_first_distinct() & ... as part of the condition to handle that.

to efficiently calculate the indices of intersecting items in the ideal and proposed lists for each user you first need to explode both of your df columns into long-format dataframes.
It assigns sequential indices (idx_ideal and idx_proposed) to the items within each list using pl.int_range grouped by user. The exploded dataframes are then joined on user and the intersecting items. This avoids global ranking issues.
Here is you originally generated data:
import polars as pl
import random

num_users = 100000
min_len = 10
max_len = 200
item_range = 10000

def generate_user_data():
    length = random.randint(min_len, max_len)
    ideal = random.sample(range(item_range), length)

    length = random.randint(min_len, max_len)
    proposed = random.sample(range(item_range), length)
    
    return ideal, proposed

data = []
for user_id in range(num_users):
    ideal, predicted = generate_user_data()
    data.append({
        'user': user_id,
        'ideal': ideal,
        'proposed': predicted
    })

df = pl.DataFrame(data)

print(df.head())

which gives
shape: (5, 3)
┌──────┬──────────────────────┬──────────────────────┐
│ user ┆ ideal                ┆ proposed             │
│ ---  ┆ ---                  ┆ ---                  │
│ i64  ┆ list[i64]            ┆ list[i64]            │
╞══════╪══════════════════════╪══════════════════════╡
│ 0    ┆ [3390, 272, … 1500]  ┆ [3760, 3166, … 3515] │
│ 1    ┆ [3055, 9338, … 818]  ┆ [2961, 7745, … 7339] │
│ 2    ┆ [1678, 1490, … 6528] ┆ [8183, 8774, … 86]   │
│ 3    ┆ [9078, 9538, … 3369] ┆ [2723, 5499, … 4258] │
│ 4    ┆ [6877, 1381, … 113]  ┆ [9058, 9365, … 4345] │
└──────┴──────────────────────┴──────────────────────┘

and here is how you should proceed:
def calculate_ndcg(df):
    ideal_df = (
        df.explode("ideal")
          .with_columns(pl.int_range(0, pl.len()).over("user").alias("idx_ideal"))
    )

    proposed_df = (
        df.explode("proposed")
          .with_columns(pl.int_range(0, pl.len()).over("user").alias("idx_proposed"))
    )

    result = (
        ideal_df.join(proposed_df, left_on=["user", "ideal"], right_on=["user", "proposed"], how="inner")
                .select(["user", "ideal", "idx_ideal", "idx_proposed"])
    )

    return result

result = calculate_ndcg(df)

print(result)

Which gives
shape: (109_425, 4)
┌───────┬───────┬───────────┬──────────────┐
│ user  ┆ ideal ┆ idx_ideal ┆ idx_proposed │
│ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---       ┆ ---          │
│ i64   ┆ i64   ┆ i64       ┆ i64          │
╞═══════╪═══════╪═══════════╪══════════════╡
│ 1     ┆ 1743  ┆ 76        ┆ 99           │
│ 5     ┆ 6051  ┆ 5         ┆ 102          │
│ 5     ┆ 8374  ┆ 31        ┆ 134          │
│ 6     ┆ 4293  ┆ 64        ┆ 100          │
│ 6     ┆ 9292  ┆ 5         ┆ 128          │
│ …     ┆ …     ┆ …         ┆ …            │
│ 99991 ┆ 9348  ┆ 14        ┆ 45           │
...
│ 99993 ┆ 884   ┆ 116       ┆ 72           │
│ 99998 ┆ 9556  ┆ 10        ┆ 186          │
│ 99999 ┆ 463   ┆ 61        ┆ 3            │
└───────┴───────┴───────────┴──────────────┘


that's kinda what I had as a result, but not sure if mapping some function at rows as proposed above would be slower/faster
